# Can I pre-empt the class path?

Tags: java, classpath

I have a library that is a drop-in extension of a commercial product.  That product is several years old and uses Sun's JAXB-2.0 libraries.

My library uses JAXB and I'm having a very bizarre error. [What might cause "JAXBElement Does not have a no-arg default constructor"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642792/)

I've discovered that this is caused by a bug in the older library.  Can I pre-empt the loaded classes to force my extension to use the "right" version of the class?

Edit:  Along with my drop-in I'm packing JAXB-2.2.5 (which is referenced on the classpath of my plugin) but I suspect that the existing JVM has already loaded 2.0 versions of the class, causing my heartache.

Comment: You can hide the loaded class path by using a custom class loader that does not delegate to its parent but attempts to load as many classes as possible by itself. This way, you could at least find out if this is the cause.

Comment: @raphw I'm in a little deeper than my understanding of the JVM.  Can you expand on this a little?

Comment: The comment field is a little short for this purpose. See the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Java `Class` is loaded by a `ClassLoader`. Once a class has been loaded, it is impossible to unload this class from a class loader. The only possibility of *getting rid* of a class is to loose all references to **all instances** of classes that this class loader has loaded and to **the reference to the classloader itself**.

Class loader's are organized in a hierarchy. By default, each class loader first asks its parent class loader to load a class. Only if the parent class loader is unable to load a class, the original class loader will attempt to do so. You could override this behavior in order to load your JAXB classes.

This is not that easy though: Assume you have a class `MyObject` that was loaded with class loader *A*. If you load the same class with class loader *B* then `MyObject.class != MyObject.class` for the two classes. This would also cause `MyObject o = getMyObjectFromOtherClassLoader()` to throw a `ClassCastException`.

Stackoverflow provides [an example of a *child first* class loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445511/how-do-i-create-a-parent-last-child-first-classloader-in-java-or-how-to-overr). The only thing remaining is to run your application without classes being loaded before the class loader gets active. This, you could do as follows (unverified code):

```
class StartupWrapper {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class.forName("com.company.Main", true, 
        new ParentLastURLClassLoader(Arrays.asList(new URL("./new-JAXB.jar"))))
      .getMethod("main", String[].class).invoke(null, args);
  }
}
```

This wrapper would start your normal application's `public static void main(String[])` method of the class `com.company.Name` using the *child-first* class loader that considers your library first. Make sure that you do not load `com.company.Main` before your explicit load. (Thus the reflective approach.)

Are you using a build tool like Maven? Can't you explicitly exclude the old library's dependeny? The legacy application will probably have similar problems with the new JAXB as your application has with the old one.

Comment: Ultimately I ended up replacing the library in-place with the updated version.  However that is a hack, and this is the "correct" solution; I'm glad that you shared the information here.